# Rails Migration: add_reference to Table but Different Column Name For Foreign Key Than Rails Convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have the following two Models:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :person
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :store
end
```

Here is the issue: I am trying to create a migration to create the foreign key within the people table. However, the column referring to the foreign key of Store is not named *store_id* as would be rails convention but is instead named *foo_bar_store_id*.

If I was following the rails convention I would do the migration like this:

```
class AddReferencesToPeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :people, :store, index: true
  end
end
```

However this will not work because the column name is not ***store_id*** but is ***foo_bar_store_id***.  So how do I specify that the foreign key name is just different, but still maintain index: true to maintain fast performance?

Comment: I think a reference, like a foreign key, should be in the model that belongs to another model. Therefore, the migration should show as 'add_reference :store, :person, index: true'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT: For those that see the tick and don't continue reading!**

While this answer achieves the goal of having an unconventional foreign key column name, with indexing, **it does not add a fk constraint to the database**. See the other answers for more appropriate solutions using `add_foreign_key` and/or 'add_reference'.

Note: ALWAYS look at the other answers, the accepted one is not always the best!

Original answer:

In your `AddReferencesToPeople` migration you can manually add the field and index using:

```
add_column :people, :foo_bar_store_id, :integer
add_index :people, :foo_bar_store_id
```

And then let your model know the foreign key like so:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :store, foreign_key: 'foo_bar_store_id'
end
```

Comment: This is not a foreign key in the database.

Comment: @baash05 Could you explain your question?

Comment: @matt I think what he is getting at, is the question is specifically asking about creating a foreign key in the table (Database level) not just at the Model level.   In newer rails, 4.2 I think, a generated  migration with references can add the foreign key in the appropriate table, to help ensure data integrity.    Having issues with formatting, but I think the relevant code would be something like `add_foreign_key :people, :stores, column: :foo_bar_store_id`

Comment: @RandyShelford Thanks, but I don't think that explains baash05's comment either. My answer includes creating the foreign key in the database via migrate, and handling non-standard foreign keys in the model. What is my answer missing? Your suggestion of `add_foreign_key` was already covered by another answer here.

Comment: How to add foreign key in data base ??

Comment: @Matt to clarify what Randy / baash05 were saying, this does not create a foreign key constraint in the database. That is, `foo_bar_store_id` can be set to an invalid store id, and the model will pass all validations. Correct me if I'm wrong, but just by adding that line in the model, rails wont throw a ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR error on saving.

Answer (score 157):

in rails 5.x you can add a foreign key to a table with a different name like this:

```
class AddFooBarStoreToPeople < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :people, :foo_bar_store, foreign_key: { to_table: :stores }
  end
end
```

Inside a `create_table` block

```
t.references :feature, foreign_key: {to_table: :product_features}
```

Comment: @inye it seems like that bug's been fixed 

Comment: This is one of those seemingly undocumented hacks that makes me both love and hate Rails at the same time.

Comment: This also works inside a `create_table` direction like: `t.references :feature, foreign_key: {to_table: :product_features}`

Comment: Love-Hate relationships are the best, but with right quantities

Comment: When I do this in MySQL, I get ActiveRecord::MismatchedForeignKey: Column `incoming_location_id` on table `inventory_incomings` does not match column `id` on `addresses`, which has type `bigint(20)`. To resolve this issue, change the type of the `incoming_location_id` column on `inventory_incomings` to be :bigint.

Comment: This is documented as an example near the bottom of the `add_reference` section since at least 5.0 https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference

Answer (score 84):

In Rails 4.2, you can also set up the model or migration with a custom foreign key name. In your example, the migration would be:

```
class AddReferencesToPeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :people, :foo_bar_store_id, :integer, index: true
    add_foreign_key :people, :stores, column: :foo_bar_store_id
  end
end
```

[Here](http://sevenseacat.net/2015/02/24/add_foreign_key_gotchas.html) is an interesting blog post on this topic. [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#foreign-keys) is the semi-cryptic section in the Rails Guides. The blog post definitely helped me.

As for associations, explicitly state the foreign key or class name like this (I think your original associations were switched as the 'belongs_to' goes in the class with the foreign key):

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :person, foreign_key: :foo_bar_store_id
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo_bar_store, class_name: 'Store'
end
```

Note that the class_name item must be a string.  The foreign_key item can be either a string or symbol. This essentially allows you to access the nifty ActiveRecord shortcuts with your semantically-named associations, like so:

```
person = Person.first
person.foo_bar_store
# returns the instance of store equal to person's foo_bar_store_id
```

See more about the association options in the documentation for [belongs_to](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to) and [has_one](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one).

Comment: Should  ` add_column :people, :foo_bar_store_id, index: true` declare a type?

Comment: @alex true - it would be better to have separate up and down methods rather than just one change method. up would probably look the same as the answer's change method, and down would remove the column.

Answer (score 12):

To expand on schpet's answer, this works in a `create_table` Rails 5 migration directive like so:

```
create_table :chapter do |t|
  t.references :novel, foreign_key: {to_table: :books}
  t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: `t.references :novel, foreign_key: {to_table: :books}` is illustrated in [Rails API documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference) however it doesn't illustrate or mention additional options available for foreign key. Such options can be found in docs for [add_foreign_key](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key) method

Comment: @JigneshGohel Thank you for linking to the documentation! I hadn't come across this before.

Answer (score 7):

```
# Migration
change_table :people do |t|
  t.references :foo_bar_store, references: :store #-> foo_bar_store_id
end

# Model
# app/models/person.rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :foo_bar_store, class_name: "Store"
end
```

Comment: glad someone added the model reference too; saved me some time!

Answer (score 0):

Under the covers add_reference is just delegating to add_column and add_index so you just need to take care of it yourself:

```
add_column :people, :foo_bar_store_id, :integer
add_index :people, :foo_bar_store_id
```

Comment: How does the Person model know foo_bar_store_id is actually a foreign key to store_id?

Comment: That doesn't belong in the migration but in the association definition in the model. As Matt has mentioned `has_one :store, foreign_key: 'foo_bar_store_id'`

Answer (score 0):

**foreign key with different column name**

```
add_reference(:products, :supplier, foreign_key: { to_table: :firms })
```

refer the documentation [Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference)